# Case when Statement Not Working with my data

Tags: sql, sql-server

While Working case statement i got stuck

For Eg i have below scenario

```
Amt         StartDate   EndDate     Port    Trade
10.00       9/21/2018   9/21/2020   NULL    NULL
54,523.00   11/14/2018  11/15/2018  NULL    NULL
756.00      11/14/2018  11/15/2018  NULL    NULL
456.00      11/14/2018  11/15/2018  NULL    NULL
86.00       11/14/2018  11/15/2018  NULL    NULL
86.00       11/14/2018  11/15/2018  NULL    NULL
453.00      11/14/2018  11/15/2018  NULL    NULL
786.00      11/14/2018  11/15/2018  NULL    NULL
86.00       11/14/2018  11/15/2018  NULL    NULL
568.00      11/14/2018  11/15/2018  NULL    NULL
12,358.00   11/14/2018  11/15/2018  NULL    NULL
45,388.00   11/5/2018   12/5/2018   NULL    NULL
75,368.00   8/9/2018    12/20/2018  call    collateral
783,678.00  7/13/2018   1/14/2019   NULL    NULL
```

- 1)what i am looking for is when startdate and enddate difference = 1
  or Port like '%call%' and Trade='collateral' then amt
- 2) when startdate and enddate difference > 7
  and Port not like '%call%' and Trade <> 'collateral' then amt

My First Condition Works

> ```
> select CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,CAST(Startdate AS DATE),CAST(Enddate AS DATE))=1
>       OR (Port like 'Call' and [Trade]='collateral') 
>    THEN amt ELSE 0 END AS money1
>    from tablename
> ```

But Second Condition not Working

```
select CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(DAY,CAST(Startdate AS DATE),CAST(Enddate AS DATE))> 7 AND 
                DATEDIFF(DAY,CAST(Startdate AS DATE),CAST(Enddate AS DATE)) <= 9999) 
                and [Trade] <> 'collateral' and Portfolio not like '%Call%'
                THEN amt ELSE 0 END AS money2    from tablename
```

excepted o/p

```
Amt         StartDate   EndDate money1              money2
10.00       9/21/2018   9/21/2020                   10.00
54,523.00   11/14/2018  11/15/2018  54,523.00   
756.00      11/14/2018  11/15/2018  756.00  
456.00      11/14/2018  11/15/2018  456.00  
86.00       11/14/2018  11/15/2018  86.00   
86.00       11/14/2018  11/15/2018  86.00   
453.00      11/14/2018  11/15/2018  453.00  
786.00      11/14/2018  11/15/2018  786.00  
86.00       11/14/2018  11/15/2018  86.00   
568.00      11/14/2018  11/15/2018  568.00  
12,358.00   11/14/2018  11/15/2018  12,358.00   
45,388.00   11/5/2018   12/5/2018                   45,388.00
75,368.00   8/9/2018    12/20/2018  75,368.00   
783,678.00  7/13/2018   1/14/2019                   783,678.00
```

Need Help i am using Sql server 2012.

Comment: Specify the expected result!

Comment: You wrote `not like '%call%'` in the question and `not like 'Call'` in the code.  They're not the same...  One has wild-cards, one has an upper case `C` *(which may or may not matter depending on your collation sequence)*.

Comment: I'm not a sql-server expert but check the result of `Portfolio not like...` when the value equals `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether `PortFolio` and `Trade` are `NULL`.
So:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,CAST(Startdate AS DATE),CAST(Enddate AS DATE))> 7 AND 
                 DATEDIFF(DAY,CAST(Startdate AS DATE),CAST(Enddate AS DATE)) <= 9999 AND
                 ([Trade] IS NULL OR [Trade] <> 'collateral') AND
                 (Portfolio IS NULL OR Portfolio NOT LIKE '%call%')
            THEN amt ELSE 0 END AS money2
FROM tablename;
```

Comment: If i am using Isnull([Trade],'') still it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Your like operator should be `'%Call%'`

```
select CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(DAY,CAST(Startdate AS DATE),CAST(Enddate AS DATE))> 7 AND 
                DATEDIFF(DAY,CAST(Startdate AS DATE),CAST(Enddate AS DATE)) <= 9999) 
                and [Trade] <> 'collateral' and Portfolio not like '%Call%'
                THEN amt ELSE 0 END AS money2 from tablename
```

Comment: Thanks For replay @fa06 i have Taken '%Call%' Still it is Not Working